# How this DocuSign normal account and developer account is different?

Tags: docusignapi, sandbox

I had created one DocuSign trial account but here i need to Use the DocuSign API then i created developer account(Sandbox) with the same credentials that i used while creating a DocuSign trial account.

Here i am having an issue .. I have tool in which i am using that API to create and send the envelope but to get the envelope status i want to use the pipeline to get the latest envelope status.

But the pipeline does not connect with the developer account and it can connect with the normal account.

Can you please let me know is there any way where we can communicate 2 accounts or can we call API with the normal trial account?

Answer (score -1):

Sandbox accounts are in the Demo environment (https://demo.docusign.net), Trial accounts are in the Production   environment (https://www.docusign.net). Those two systems are effectively air-gapped and cannot communicate.

In order to make API calls against your trial account, you will need to authenticate as a member of that trial account, which means hitting the correct authentication server (account-d.docusign.com for demo / account.docusign.com for trial/production), using the correct credentials and account ID.

Comment: This answer has no link to demo trial prod.